# configuring SpriteSortMode and BlendState

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, alphablending

I'm drawing to the sprite batch starting with things in the background and ending with the forground.

I wish to be able to use any color and transparency, or if it makes it faster possibly any color and a single given transparency which is quite faint. I need to be able to draw dark on light as well as light on dark or similar shades but of different colors over each other.

What is the best SpriteSortMode and BlendState to use?

I'm thinking SpriteSortMode.Deferred because everything is going on in the order I want it rendered anyway and BlendState.NonPremultiplied, although I'm not sure what NonPremultiplied means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deffered renders all of the textures in the order you called draw when you call sprite batch.end. So this is the best in your situation.

> SpriteSortMode.Deferred

You probably want BlendState.AlphaBlend assuming that you are using the content processor.If you are using Texture2D.FromStream use BlendState.NonPremultiplied.

> BlendState.NonPremultiplied

Comment: Is "spriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D..." the content processor or FromStream?

Comment: Yes, NonPremultiplied works, AlphaBlend dosn't, in AlphaBlend for example white transparent things appear white and solid, tyvm.

Comment: By processor or stream I meant how you got the texture off of the disk. If you added the image to a content project and loaded it in though Content.Load<Texture2d>("asset") the processor be defualt premultiplies the alpha. If you use Texture2d.FromStream() then it loads the texture as is on disk with without premultiplied alpha.